# Highcharts pie chart size doesn't fill smaller containers even with dataLabels disabled

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to get a highcharts pie chart to fill its container (i.e with data labels and legend disabled).
The auto-scaling on highcharts seems to work ok for larger containers, but on smaller ones (e.g. 50x50 px) its nowhere near the full container size;
[image: Whitespace example]

```html
plotOptions: {
  pie: {
    size:'250%' //COMMENT OUT TO SEE THE PROBLEM
  }
}
```

I've played about with most options now and I can't see a way to set it other than using **plotOptions.pie.size**, but even that is not consisent.
Of course I could just set the absolute value in pixels, but that seems a bit nasty in a dynamic environment... or I can set the % value, but even that isn't consistent in how much additional percent is needed (seems to get much higher the smaller the container).

E.G., 250%;
[image: 'size:'250%']

[Example fiddle modified from highcharts example](https://jsfiddle.net/mattscotty/r6a21dkm/)

I feel like I'm missing something here, suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space is left for sliced points, set:

```
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            slicedOffset: 0,
            ...
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ukepr4x6/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.slicedOffset